# How to get pixels inside of a quadrilateral defined by four points in OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, chess

I'm new to OpenCV, but with a bit of luck and a lot of time I was able to hack together some code that detects individual cells in a chessboard like so:

[image: chessboard]

The image frame is being stored in a [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) and the corners are being stored in a [MatOfPoint2f](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint2f.html).

Code to show how I'm using the matrices to draw the cells individually:

```
private void draw(final Mat frame) {
    for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE - 1; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE - 1; y++) {
            final int index = x + y * BOARD_SIZE;
            final Point topLeft = cornerPoints.get(index);
            final Point bottomLeft = cornerPoints.get(index + BOARD_SIZE);
            final Point topRight = cornerPoints.get(index + 1);
            final Point bottomRight = cornerPoints.get(index + 1 + BOARD_SIZE);

            // left line
            Imgproc.line(frame, topLeft, bottomLeft, DEBUG_COLOR);
            // right line
            Imgproc.line(frame, topRight, bottomRight, DEBUG_COLOR);
            // top line
            Imgproc.line(frame, topLeft, topRight, DEBUG_COLOR);
            // bottom line
            Imgproc.line(frame, bottomLeft, bottomRight, DEBUG_COLOR);
        }
}
```

How would I use the four points (the corners of the cells) to get the RGB values of the pixels inside of the each quadrilateral?

Answer (score 2):

Create a mask from your vertices. You can use fillPoly for that.
Then iterate over pixels. If pixel(x,y) is valid in your mask, read RGB else continue. Restrict pixel iteration range using your extreme vertices.

Comment: if outer contour is known, `cv::drawContours` can be used too, not sure which one is faster. To speed up the mask processing, a ROI can be computed with `cv::boundingRect` which can be used as sumbinage for mask and image.

Comment: Thank you both! It sounds like it'll work great. I'll test it out once I return home

Comment: @Micka do either of you know why when I'm getting incorrect RGB values? I'm getting it by doing `byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
                            frame.get(x_, y_, rgb);` and for a white/grey pixel it's returning -117, -107, -109 into the byte array. And it's not just because it's unsigned, as that color would be black when it's suppose to be white/grey. I know it's checking the correct pixel

Comment: sorry, no idea because I dont have openCV java experience. Isnt openCV java using doubles for pixel retrieval?

Comment: Is your image a byte image?
Does this work: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values ?
Sry I'm not an OpenCV expert

Comment: @Micka I forgot x and y are swapped in the matrices..... literally spent a day troubleshooting it lol

Comment: @64test1234 it is not swapped, it is matrix notation ;) nice to hear you could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Masking works. If you have lots of polygons, or not too much RAM, a point-in-polygon test may be more efficient, especially if you can guarantee that your quadrilaterals are convex. See [this reference](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/)